# ansible dynamic inventory kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to use the kubernetes plugin in ansible to be able to use a dynamic inventory based on my k8 cluster. I have followed this doc https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/kubernetes_scenarios/k8s_inventory.html however i keep getting a failed to parse error.

```
# ansible-inventory --list -i k8s.yaml
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/k8s.yaml with ansible_collections.kubernetes.core.plugins.inventory.k8s plugin: Invalid value "kubernetes.core.k8s" for configuration option "plugin_type: inventory
plugin: ansible_collections.kubernetes.core.plugins.inventory.k8s setting: plugin ", valid values are: ['k8s']
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/k8s.yaml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}
```

**extract from ansible.cfg**

```
# egrep -i "\[inventory\]|kubernetes" ansible.cfg
[inventory]
enable_plugins = kubernetes.core.k8s
```

**k8s.yaml**

```
# cat k8s.yaml
plugin: kubernetes.core.k8s
```

The error suggests that `kubernetes.core.k8s` is an invalid value and that valid values are `['k8s']`. yet this is exactly whats in the documentation, I have tried all manor of altering the plugin name with no success.

Can anyone steer me on what i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get it working by editing `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/inventory/k8s.py` it seems my version only listed `k8s` as a pluggin name, I replaced with, `kubernetes.core.k8s` and it worked

```py
   options:
      plugin:
         description: token that ensures this is a source file for the 'k8s' plugin.
         required: True
         choices: ['kubernetes.core.k8s']
```

I did plan to raise it as a PR on the project but seems this was already updated several months back so I must have just had outdated files.

https://github.com/ansible-collections/kubernetes.core/blob/60933457e81fcfa1000f556b2bc3425bbf080602/plugins/inventory/k8s.py#L27